# Combining elements of lists whose name has a pattern

Tags: r

I'm working with several lists of strings :

```
list1 <- c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd")
list2 <- c("eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh", "iii")
list3 <- c("jjj", "kkk")
list4 <- c("lll", "mmm", "nnn")
```

I would like to combine all elements in these lists into one long list:

```
all.lists <- c(list1, list2, list3, list4)

all.lists[1] "aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd" "eee" "fff" "ggg" "hhh" "iii" "jjj" "kkk" "lll" "mmm" "nnn"
```

In reality I'm working with a large number of lists that share a pattern in their names and it is impractical to type every list out individually.

All my approaches to combine lists according to a pattern have resulted in "lists of lists" or lists of list names as strings, not in the result I'd like. Here are some examples of what didn't work:

```
all.lists <- c(mget(ls(pattern = "list")))
> str(all.lists)
List of 4

library(rlist)
all.lists <- list.append(ls(pattern = "list"))
[1] "list1"     "list2"     "list3"     "list4"
```

How do I combine them into one long list? Thank you!

Comment: `l <- mget(ls(pattern = "list"))`; `unlist(l)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get `mget` + `unlist`:

```r
l <- mget(ls(pattern = "list")) 
unlist(l, use.names = FALSE)
#[1] "aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd" "eee" "fff" "ggg" "hhh" "iii" "jjj" "kkk" "lll" "mmm" "nnn"
```

Or with `Reduce` + `c`:

```r
Reduce(c, l)
#[1] "aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd" "eee" "fff" "ggg" "hhh" "iii" "jjj" "kkk" "lll" "mmm" "nnn"
```

Answer (score 1):

In one step you could do:

```r
do.call(c, c(mget(ls(pattern = "^list")), use.names = FALSE))
# [1] "aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd" "eee" "fff" "ggg" "hhh" "iii" "jjj" "kkk" "lll" "mmm" "nnn"
```